# Factorials in a binomial expansion proof

Tags: solution-verification, binomial-coefficients

By considering $(1+x)^{2n}$ when $x=1$, prove that $\sum ^n_{r=0} {2n\choose r}=2^{2n-1}+\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2\left(n!\right)^2}$

I am able to prove $\sum ^n_{r=0} {2n\choose r}=2^{2n-1}$, but nowhere does the term $\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2\left(n!\right)^2}$
pop up so I am bewildered about that.

Firstly after letting $x=1$, I have $$2^{2n}=\binom{2n}{0}+\binom{2n}{1}+...+\binom{2n}{n}+...+\binom{2n}{2n}$$

And by symmetry, $$2^{2n-1}=\binom{2n}{0}+\binom{2n}{1}+...+\binom{2n}{n}=\sum _{r=0}^n\:\binom{2n}{r}$$

Where does the factorial bit come from?

Comment: Hint: how is $\binom{n}{k}$ defined?

Comment: $n$ choose $k$, basically the combinations formula

Comment: $1+2+1=4$, so by symmetry $1+2=2$, are you serious?

Comment: hmm yes it seems ive made a mistake. Ill try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n \choose k}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n \choose k}=2^{2n}~~~~~(1)$$
LHS on (1) can be rearranged as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n \choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n \choose k}+ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} {2n \choose k}=S+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {2n \choose j+n+1}$$
In the last part we have used $k=n+1+j$, Next use $j=n-1-p$ in it to get
$$2^{2n}=S+\sum_{p=n-1}^{0} {2n \choose 2n-p}
=S+\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {2n \choose p}=2S-{2n \choose n}$$
Finally, we get $$S=2^{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2} {2n \choose n}=2^{2n-1} +\frac{(2n)!}{2~n!^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$2^4=1+4+6+4+1=2(1+4+6)-6$$ should be enough to let you see where this term is coming from.
($2^2=1+2+1=2(1+2)-2$ as well ;-)

For odd powers, you don't have an equivalent:

$$2^3=1+3+3+1=2(1+3).$$

Comment: ahh interesting thanks for your input. Wouldn't have noticed this myself - that odd powers wont produce the "extra" term

Comment: @user71207: this is precisely what you missed from the beginning: the expansion has $n+1$ terms, which flips the parity.

Comment: do you mean $2n+1$?

Comment: @user71207: no, I mean power $n\to n+1$ terms. Sorry for ambiguity.